# Where and how do I implement SlidesJS within a BackboneJS app?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm new to BackboneJS, and I'm working on a small app that has a slideshow in one of the views. I'm not sure where to put the code that starts the slideshow in the view.

I'm using **[SlidesJS](http://slidesjs.com)**, and I'm wondering where to throw this code:

```
$("#slides").slides();
```

If I put it just within the jQuery ready handler (outside of the BackboneJS app), it gets the slideshow going only once and it naturally doesn't continue to work as the view is re-rendered.

For whatever reason, I'm also not getting it to work (and I'm wondering if it's a good idea) if I put the code in within the view's render function either:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    this.$("#slides").slides();
    return this;
}
```

Where is the best place to implement SlidesJS or jQuery tools like it in BackboneJS?

**Thanks!**

Comment: Is `#slides` inside your view's `el`? Does SlidesJS need `#slides` to be in the DOM (for say size and position information) before it can work? You can check the latter by doing `setTimeout(function() { $('#slides').slides() }, 0)`.

Comment: I think that's it right there. The `el` element is not in the DOM, and it looks like it does need to be. The setTimeout trick worked. How then, do I implement this so that the slides() method is called after the `el` is in the DOM (without running it on a timeout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like SlidesJS needs everything rendered and in the DOM before it can do its thing, this is probably because it needs size and position information to line up the slides; I've had similar issues with Google Maps and the solution was to put off the binding until *after* the view's `el` has been added to the DOM:

```
var $slides = this.$(...);
setTimeout(function() {
    $slides.slides()
}, 0);
```

and then the caller will:

```
$something.append(v.render().el);
```

Using `setTimeout` with a zero timeout is a trick to get something run after the browser has control and has updated the DOM. You could also use [`_.defer`](http://underscorejs.org/#defer):

```
_(function() { $slides.slides() }).defer();
```

but that's just a fancy way of calling `setTimeout`.

The downside of this approach is that you're assuming that the caller will call your view's `render` and then immediately add your `el` to the DOM. This isn't much of a downside though, the `x.append(v.render().el)` is standard Backbone usage.

This sort of thing smells a bit kludgey but it is pretty safe and sometimes you have to kludge your way around problems.

Comment: Thank you! In this case, I've moved the `slides()` code to a method that gets called from the router after the view is added to the DOM, and we're in business. I will keep this solution in mind as well, though, as I'm sure this will come up again.